# Numbers not being passed from object to method in javascript

Tags: javascript, object, methods, numbers

I'm trying to create an object that contains 2 methods. The first uses two prompts to input two numbers, the second adds the numbers together. When i run the code the numbers are either concatenating or `NaN` is being returned. I've used `parseInt()` on the numbers but without effect.

What is wrong with this code ? Why are the numbers not being passed ?

```
var summator = {

  val1: 0,
  val2: 0,
  run: function() {
      this.val1 = prompt('enter a value');
      var newVal1 = parseInt(this.val1);

      this.val2 = prompt('enter another value');
      var newVal2 = parseInt(this.val2);
  },
  sum: function(newVal1, newVal2) {
        alert(newVal1 + newVal2);
  }
}

summator.run();
summator.sum();
```

Comment: What's the input/output where the numbers are being concatenated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify code as follows-

```
var summator = {

  val1: 0,
  val2: 0,
  run: function() {
      this.val1 = prompt('enter a value');
      newVal1 = parseInt(this.val1);

      this.val2 = prompt('enter another value');
      newVal2 = parseInt(this.val2);
  },
  sum: function() {
        alert(newVal1 + newVal2);
  }
}

summator.run();
summator.sum();
```

### Reason

The stetement with `var newVal1` in the function `run()` makes `newVal1` local to the scope of `run()` and hence within `sum()` `newVal1` and `newVal2` are not available and hence you could not access those two values.

Hence I have made these two variable global to the scope and hence you dont need them to be specified in the parameter list of `sum()`.

### Solution without `newVal1` and `newVal2`

```
var summator = {

  val1: 0,
  val2: 0,
  run: function() {
      this.val1 = prompt('enter a value');
      this.val1 = parseInt(this.val1);

      this.val2 = prompt('enter another value');
      this.val2 = parseInt(this.val2);
  },
  sum: function() {
        alert(this.val1 + this.val2);
  }
}

summator.run();
summator.sum();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not passing anything into `sum`.

Your code expects two parameters.

`newVal1` and `newVal2` in the `run` function have nothing to do with the variables of the same name in `sum`

Comment: Particularly since `newVal1` and `newVal2` are local to `run()`, so `sum()` would never see them anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'd get `run` to return the values harvested from the user input, then pass them in for the `sum` method:

```
var summator = {
  run: function() {
    var val1 = prompt('enter a value');    
    var val2 = prompt('enter another value');

    return {val1: parseInt(val1), val2: parseInt(val2)};
  },
  sum: function(newVal1, newVal2) {
    alert(newVal1 + newVal2);
  }
}

var vals = summator.run();
summator.sum(vals.val1, vals.val2);
```

I slightly altered your code, as this val 1 and val2 wasn't necessary to store as they were not used after the function return.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code as below:

```
var summator = {

   val1: 0,
   val2: 0,
   run: function() {
      this.val1 = prompt('enter a value');
      var newVal1 = parseInt(this.val1);

      this.val2 = prompt('enter another value');
      var newVal2 = parseInt(this.val2);
      summator.sum(newVal1, newVal2);
   },
   sum: function(newVal1, newVal2) {
       alert(newVal1 + newVal2);
   }
}


summator.run();
```

And it will return addition of both, since you have already parsed inputs.

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/BKG7L/